# How do bind a button to an OK Dialog result with winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, dialogresult

I Have a `Form` that I have opened up as a dialog. On the `Form` I have a <kbd>cancel</kbd> and a <kbd>correct</kbd> button, I need to get the positive feedback from the form when the user selects the <kbd>correct</kbd> button. How would I go about linking the <kbd>correct</kbd> button to the `OK` Dialog result?

Comment: It says `when not using buttons` but the answer covers your case.

Comment: On your form's properties, there is `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN Button.DialogResult Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) comes this answer:

```
private void InitializeMyButton()
{
    // Create and initialize a Button.
    Button button1 = new Button();

    // Set the button to return a value of OK when clicked.
    button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

    // Add the button to the form.
    Controls.Add(button1);
}
```

applied to your case you would just simply assign this to the property of your <kbd>correct</kbd> button:

```
correct_btn.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```